# I need to transform a short piece of code that adds gaps to a phrase and have no idea how to do it

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code that adds some gaps into a word/phrase like this:

```
"I drove everywhere by car" > "I d_o_e e_e_y_h_r_ _y c_r_"
```

How can it be transformed so it would to a result that is a little different:

```
"I drove everywhere by car" > "I d___e e___y___r_ b_ c__"
```

The difference is that it would show the first letter of every word, then make a 3-letter gap, and, if the word is long enough, show the 5th letter, another 3-letter gap and so on.

The piece of code:

```
var str = document.getElementById("dropped-v").innerHTML;
letters = '';
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) { 
    if (i % 2 != 0 && str[i] != ' ') { 
        letters += '<span class="hint">_</span>'; 
    } 
    else {
       letters += str[i]; 
    } 
}
document.getElementById("dropped-v").innerHTML = letters;
```

Comment: What happens right now?

Comment: Why does the first example end in `c_r_` rather than `c_r`? And why does `by` map to `_y` rather than `b_`?

Comment: Re  "c_r_ rather than c_r" - it just replaced the point mark ("."), didn't notice that. @jarmod

Comment: And 'by' maps to '_y' because the existing code simply changes every second character to _. @jarmod

Comment: Your current code seems to iterate through each character of the input phrase, but you might rather want to split the phrase into an array of words and then iterate through each word and replace characters with underscores as necessary. You can do the splitting by `var words = str.split(' ')`.

Comment: @MrMythical I'm sorry, I don't understand the question

Comment: @pkorhone thank you, that's exactly what I want to do. Where do I put this line though?

Comment: In your current code, you can use it anytime after you have defined `var str`. So you can try adding that to the second line and then investigating what the newly defined array `words` contains :)

Comment: I meant what is happening instead of what you want

Comment: @MrMythical I get "I d_o_e e_e_y_h_r_ _y c_r_" instead of "I d___e e___y___r_ b_ c__"

Comment: @pkorhone if I do exactly that, this array contains "I,drove,everywhere,by,car". How do I turn it into "I d___e e___y___r_ b_ c__"?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it for simple sentences without periods. You can add period support and HTML injection as needed.

```js
let MASK = '_';

function obfuscate_word(word) {
  const letters = [...word];
  const mask_letters = letters.map((letter, i) => i % 4 == 0 ? letter : MASK);
  return mask_letters.join('');
}

function obfuscate_sentence(sentence) {
  const words = sentence.split(' ');
  const mask_words = words.map(word => obfuscate_word(word));
  return mask_words.join(' ');
}

const s = "I drove everywhere by car"
console.log(s);
console.log(obfuscate_sentence(s));
```

If you want to, you can replace the MASK and get/set your HTML something like this:

```
MASK = '<span class="hint">_</span>';
const e = document.getElementById("dropped-v");
e.innerHTML = obfuscate_sentence(e.innerHTML);
```

This assumes that the inner HTML of the `dropped-v` element is a simple sentence (and not a previously-obfuscated sentence that includes markup, for example).

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I have very limited understanding of how it works. 

Do I put it like this?:

var str = document.getElementById("dropped-v").innerHTML;
function obfuscate_word(word) {
  const letters = [...word];
  const mask_letters = letters.map((letter, index) => index % 4 == 0 ? letter : '_');
  return mask_letters.join('');
}

function obfuscate_sentence(sentence) {
  const words = sentence.split(' ');
  const mask_words = words.map(word => obfuscate_word(word));
  return mask_words.join(' ');
}
document.getElementById("dropped-v").innerHTML = letters;

Comment: Have updated my answer to help. This code is reasonably simple and it's worth spending a few minutes to understand it if you're planning to use it, because you may want to make changes at some point.